# How to generate jobs/tasks dynamically from JSON object in Azure Devops yaml

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml pipeline task that is creating a JSON string and assigning it to an output variable using Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable syntax.

What I want is to use that JSON variable to dynamically create some other jobs/tasks.

Say the JSON contains a collection like this
[
{projectPath: "source\client\webui\webui.csproj", name: "testUI", type: "webUI"},
{projectPath: "source\microservice\test\test.csproj", name: 'testService', type: "microservice"}
]

I would like to then take that JSON and generate a pipeline that runs job(s) or even task(s) for each record.

This is VERY general pseudocode - what I need is the actual syntax, if this is even doable.

$each project
{

- job: DoSomeWorkFor$(project.name)
  steps:

  - template: 'do.build.yml'
    parameters:
    projectPath: $(project.path)
    type: $(project.type)
    }

I'll also point out that if the above is not a recommend approach, I am open to other options using Azure Devops with a monorepo.

Comment: The more I did, the more  wonder if I am using the tools incorrectly. They support string join, but not split. They support converting a complex object to a JSON string, but not string back to a JSON object. And they don't support passing complex objects as parameters or even creating them as variables. Seems like Azure Devops is almost intentionally making a decision not to do what I am trying to do.